# 1 result using COUNT in multiple columns Using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table called questions Survey. I sent them a survey in Jan_2018, March_2018, Sept_2018, Jan_2017, March_2017, Sept_2017. I'm trying to get the sum of people that received the email and answer the questions. The table only has YES( Y), NO (N)]. Not sure, if this queries is the best to use as it gave me a lower numbers that I think is incorrect. I used this queries:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS 'Questions_Results'                                                    
FROM [DEV].[dbo].[Questions_survey]
WHERE [Jan_2018] = 'Y' 
    AND [March_2018] = 'Y' 
    AND [Sept_2018] = 'Y'
    AND [Jan_2017] = 'Y'
    AND [March_2017] = 'Y'
    AND [Sept_2017] = 'Y' 
    AND [2017_Jan_Test_open] = 'Y'
    AND [2017_March_Test_open] = 'Y'
    AND [2017_Sept_Test_open] = 'Y'
```

Comment: Is this really MySQL?

Comment: I think you want to replace the AND's with OR's.

Comment: Use an OR instead of AND

Comment: Can you post the schema for Questions_survey? The reason I ask is that count might be counting questions (which I presume are multiple per survey) which would give you bad numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the overall number of people who answered your survey, just use OR instead of AND :

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS 'Questions_Results'                                                    
FROM [DEV].[dbo].[Questions_survey]
WHERE [Jan_2018] = 'Y' 
    OR [March_2018] = 'Y' 
    OR [Sept_2018] = 'Y'
    OR [Jan_2017] = 'Y'
    OR [March_2017] = 'Y'
    OR [Sept_2017] = 'Y' 
    OR [2017_Jan_Test_open] = 'Y'
    OR [2017_March_Test_open] = 'Y'
    OR [2017_Sept_Test_open] = 'Y'
```

I think this is the best way to do it.

Comment: If I only want the results of people who did receive and took it the survey does OR still apply ?

Comment: I don't know , it depends on what 'Y' means in your table.

Answer (score 0):

`AND` returns the count of records where survey has been generated for all months. If you want total individual survey numbers use `OR`

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS 'Questions_Results' FROM [DEV].[dbo].[Questions_survey] WHERE [Jan_2018] = 'Y' OR [March_2018] = 'Y' OR [Sept_2018] = 'Y' OR [Jan_2017] = 'Y' OR [March_2017] = 'Y' OR [Sept_2017] = 'Y' OR [2017_Jan_Test_open] = 'Y' OR [2017_March_Test_open] = 'Y' OR [2017_Sept_Test_open] = 'Y'
```

---

Comment: i do want the overall of anyone who received the survey and took it.
Survey SENT                      Survey Taken
2017: YES                          2017: Yes
2018: yes
schema:

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of emails sent, then presumably you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Questions_Results                                                   
FROM [DEV].[dbo].[Questions_survey]
WHERE 'Y' IN (Jan_2018, March_2018, Sept_2018, Jan_2017, March_2017, Sept_2017);
```

I'm not sure what the "test_open" columns are.  They are not mentioned in the question itself.  Are they related to "answering the questions"?

If a "person" can be on more than one row, then you may need `COUNT(DISTINCT)` using whatever column specifies the person:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) AS Questions_Results                                                   
FROM [DEV].[dbo].[Questions_survey]
WHERE 'Y' IN (Jan_2018, March_2018, Sept_2018, Jan_2017, March_2017, Sept_2017);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,
The test_open mean they actually they took the survey. I guess, I want to count of people who:
Test were sent in 2017 and 2018 and took it.